Files to be ignored and not ignore during search in VS Code
I am using search and replace in VS Code, I need to replace data in index.html file and exclude all other files in folder, how to do it?

Go to the Search tab and use the "files to include" field to filter "index.html" then use the top 2 fields to search and replace text as usual.


In this case it searches in all index.html of the project, but I need to specifically in a folder. Let's say in folder "shop", replace data in all index.html files, but not replace in other files.

In that instance you would want something like */shop/index.html or perhaps */shop/*index.html.

thank you, this method helped: shop/*/index.html
